# Prove $\int_{t}^{\infty}(1-3 x^{-4}) e^{-x^{2} / 2} d x=(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^{3}}) e^{-t^{2} / 2}$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $t>0$, prove
$$
\int_{t}^{\infty}\left(1-3 x^{-4}\right) e^{-x^{2} / 2} d x=\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^{3}}\right) e^{-t^{2} / 2}.
$$

I have tried integration by part. But I cannot get the answer.
The equation arises in the context of normal p.d.f.

Comment: Note that when $f$ is continuous and integrable, proving $\int_t^\infty f(x)\,dx = F(t)$ is generally easier than evaluating $\int_t^\infty f(x)\,dx.$  In the former situation, it suffices to show $F'(t) = -f(t)$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty} F(t) = 0$, while in the latter, you'd likely need to resort to integration techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the substitution $u=\frac{x^2}{2}$. Then you have

$$ \int_t^{\infty}(1-3x^{-4}e^{-x^2}{2}dx=\int_{\frac{t^2}{2}}^{\infty} (1-\frac{3}{4}u^{-2})e^{-u} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}du=\int_{\frac{t^2}{2}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2u}}e^{-u} -\frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}}u^{-\frac{5}{2}}e^{-u}du.$$
Then use integration by parts with $f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2u}}$ and $g'=e^{-u}$,
$$\int_{\frac{t^2}{2}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2u}}e^{-u}=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}\frac{1}{t}-\int_{\frac{t^2}{2}}^{\infty} e^{-u} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}u^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$
and with $f'=u^{-\frac{5}{2}}$, $g=e^{-u}$,
$$\int_{\frac{t^2}{2}}^{\infty}-\frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}}u^{-\frac{5}{2}}e^{-u}du=-\frac{1}{t^3}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}+\int_{\frac{t^2}{2}}^{\infty}e^{-u}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}u^{-\frac{3}{2}}du.$$
Then add the two terms and you get what you wanted.